# gin golang: what is gin.Context.Keys

Tags: http, go, go-gin

I was tring to use the method `context.GetBool` ([here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/context.go#L280)) from the **go-gin** framework with some query params.
It doesn't work as excepted and I think the `Context.Keys` is not populated by query params.

So my question is: what is `gin.Context.Keys`, and how should it be populated when making a request ?

PS: the question was already asked [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1875), but left without a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The `Keys` field is what backs up Gin's Context implementation of `context.Context` interface as a request-scoped key/value carrier.

---

> I think the Context.Keys is not populated by query params.

Correct. `Context.Keys` is unrelated to query params. Query params are available with [`Context.Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Query).

About `Keys` instead, the document on the struct field reads:

> Keys is a key/value pair exclusively for the **context of each request**.

And these key/value pairs are accessible with [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Get) and [`Set`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Set). The docs of this latter one are:

> Set is used to store a new key/value pair exclusively for this context. It also lazy initializes c.Keys if it was not used previously.

Hence the field is similar to `context` package's `Context.WithValue` and `Context.Value`, e.g. **request-scoped parameters**. Gin's Context `Keys` is the exported map that stores the raw key/value pairs. The methods such as `GetBool` are convenience, in that you don't have to type-assert the `interface{}` values yourself.

Unlike other web frameworks, Gin's Context does not wrap a `context.Context` value (except for `c.Request.Context`), instead it directly implements the interface. This includes the [`Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Value) method itself, which also accesses the underlying `Keys` field.

By the way, an important difference from the standard lib `context` implementation is that `context.Context` accepts `interface{}` keys, whereas Gin's Context accepts only `string` keys.